# My last subscription doesn't close the subscription

Tags: php, sql, innodb

I have huge real time troubles with my system right now. Imagine you can enroll a subscription. Let's say maximum is 3 participants. When 3 people is reached the subscription must be closed, for everyone! This is a part of my code:

```
               function subscription_data($subid)  // activated by ajax
               { 
                    $sql = 'SELECT subEnrolled, subStatus FROM subscription WHERE subID=:subid';
                    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->bindparam("subid", $subid);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    $subEnrolled = $row['subEnrolled'];
                    $subParticipants = '3';

                    // is this subscription already closed ???
                    if (!($row['subStatus'] =='1'))  // if '1' not run anymore
                    {    
                         if( $subEnrolled+1 == $subParticipants )
                         {
                              $status1 = '1'; // close subscription for the NEXT fire
                              $sql = 'UPDATE subscription SET subStatus=:substatus WHERE subID=:subid';
                              $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
                              $stmt->bindparam("subid", $subid);
                              $stmt->bindparam("substatus",$status1);

                              $stmt->execute(); 
                         }    

                         //
                         // DO SOMETHING MORE
                         //

                         // Add to one enrollment
                         $add1enroll = '1';
                         $sql = 'UPDATE subscription SET subEnrolled=subEnrolled+:subenrolled WHERE subID=:subid';
                         $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
                         $stmt->bindparam("subenrolled", $add1enroll);
                         $stmt->bindparam("subid", $subid);
                         $stmt->execute();
                    }
               }
```

My problem is that I would like to close this subscription before more than e.g. 3 people enroll it. However if I click my AJAX buttons fast to fire the function, with multiple accounts (4), I can actually get 4 enrolments out of 3. I tried to avoid this with the above `if( $subEnrolled+1 == $subParticipants )` - a special case for the last participant who enroll the subscription. It does not work.

Hope you understand my variables, I tried to make them as logic as possible. The above code is also inside a `transaction()` function, and I use InnoDB tables in general, however if I change this, I still have same problem.

Comment: How are you keeping track of how many subscriptions there are?

Comment: in `// DO SOMETHING` I `UPDATE subscription` table and add 1 enrollment each time function run. When function start I extract this number (enrollment number) and put it in the variable `$subEnrolled`.. The above was just for illustrative purpose

Comment: You seem to be adding an enrollment even if you close the subscription. That maybe causing a problem.

Comment: ok I tried, to move the `if( $subEnrolled+1 == $subParticipants )` block below, that did not help :/

Answer (score 1):

When you wrap statements in a transaction, a table lock is only applied when you try to run an INSERT, UPDATE, or other such statement.

You should add another condition to the WHERE clause that checks how many enrollments there are.

```
UPDATE subscription
SET subEnrolled=subEnrolled+:subenrolled
WHERE
  subID=:subid AND
  subEnrolled  < 3
```

Probably need to remove the `+1` from `if( $subEnrolled+1 == $subParticipants )` too.

Comment: Ok Terminus, I think you got me on the right road.. Until now it look like it works, I will finish-test it tomorrow to be sure of this important issue. I will remember to get back, thank you !

Comment: I tried a lot of combinations. Unfortunately I can still enroll more than 3 times. Without the `+1` in  `if( $subEnrolled+1 == $subParticipants )` and with your suggestion it will finish the subscription just after first enrollment, due to the WHERE clause `subEnrolled  < 3` just need to be below 3. I also tried to change this WHERE claus to `subEnrolled+1 = 3` which again allow for more than 3 subscriptions if I fire it fast...